# What is the easiest way to extract a variable outside Unity for use in another program?

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine

I am trying to find a way to extract this Time Manager variable I have in Unity in order to be able to use it in another program in C++ to graph some data. I have even went as far as to finding pointers to the memory address of the Time Manager and reading with ReadProcessMemory, but as you know each time you push out another build of Unity or change something, the pointers eventually get invalidated.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you could write to a file

Comment: You can use any form of [interprocess communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications). I believe a [named pipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipes) may be appropriate. Note that it is possible to run C++ code in Unity, by writing a DLL that is loaded in Unity as a [plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html).